# How to make elements fall continuously in React Native?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have a large array of objects, I want them to appear one after the other with animation, I'm having an idea to show each element in the array then change its state and show the new element after the animation is over, I'm new with react native so am having a lot of trouble, hope someone can help, here are a few things I tried with 2 elements and also try many ways, or you can come up with a new way, but I am getting stuck and it is not can work as expected

[You can see this picture to understand better](https://asset.cloudinary.com/dyrjg8n6f/ca7567f7a4d958c9477d5f63809fac0d)

```
const [list, setList] = useState([
    { a: '', b: '', c: '' },
    { a: '', b: '', c: '' },
])

const animated1 = new Animated.Value(0) 
const animated2 = new Animated.Value(0) 

const [buf1, setBuf1] = useState(0)
const [buf2, setBuf2] = useState(1)
const [delay, setDelay] = useState(1000)
 
useEffect(() => {
        Animated.sequence([
            Animated.timing(animated1, {
            toValue: 300,
            duration: 2000,
            useNativeDriver: true,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            }),
        ]).start(()=>{
            setinAnimationA(true)
            if (inAnimationA){
                setinAnimationA(false)
                setBuf1(buf1=>buf1+1)
                if (delay > 0){setDelay(0)}
            }
        })
 }, [animated1])

 useEffect(() => {
        Animated.sequence([
            Animated.timing(animated2, {
            toValue: 300,
            duration: 2000,
            useNativeDriver: true,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            delay: delay
            }),
        ]).start(()=>{
            setinAnimationB(true)
            if (inAnimationB){
                setinAnimationB(false)
                setBuf2(buf2=>buf2+1)
            }
        })
}, [animated2]);

return (
<View>
 <Animated.View style={{top: 0, transform: [{translateY: animated1}]}}>
     <Text>{List[buf1]}</Text>
 </Animated.View>
 <Animated.View style={{top: 0, transform: [{translateY: animated2}]}}>
     <Text>{List[buf2]}</Text>
 </Animated.View>     
</View> 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index key of your FlatList/List and multiply it with a constant

Comment: I can't display all the elements in that array at once, I want to display only about 10 elements (about the size of the screen) then followed by another 10 elements after 10 animations ends

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).